# Access to an HTML element of a HTML page embedded into a <div>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an html file called `index.php` that include a `<div>` from another html file called `addNotes.html`. I load the file on the `<div>` with this js function from `indexjs.js`:

`mainDiv.innerHTML = '<object id="newPage" type="text/html" data="addNotes.html" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></object>';`

Now, `addNotes.html` has a button called "compute" and when I click on it, I would like to call the function defined in indexjs.js and but when I try to call it and look at the result in the console, I got this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null**

because i want to change the css of an element in the first page.
Is there a solution?

Thank you and sorry for my english

Comment: If you're using PHP, why haven't you just added the addNotes.html using PHP `include()`? Then it becomes part of the index.php page and will work with other resources no problem. Just change addNotes.html to addNotes.php and then stick `<?php include('addNotes.php'); ?>` to your index.php page

Comment: You know how to use php?

Comment: I have already tried it but it doesn't work to me because i need to open the second page when i click in a button on the first page